# Send kargs to gtk.ListStore

Tags: python-2.7, pygtk

I'm using TreeView with ListStore. my code goes like this:

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        .
        .
        types = int, str, str, int
        myTree, myStore = b.create_treeview(types)
        .
        .


class b:
    def create_treeview(types):
        #create gtk tree view object
        #return treeview and store (for the columns)
        store = gtk.ListStore(types[0], types[1], types[2], types[3])
        treeView = gtk.TreeView(store)
        treeView.set_rules_hint(True)
        return treeView, store
```

As you can see, class b doing some code work for class b.
The variable *types* helping me send all types to the store. The problem is the way I'm using it at class b. Is there any why to make it more generic for re-use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to define `types` in `a`, unless you use it again elsewhere:

```
myTree, myStore = b.create_treeview((int, str, str, int))
```

and you can make `b` more generic with:

```
store = gtk.ListStore(*types)
```

which will "unpack" the tuple of types into separate arguments to `ListStore` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761) for further explanation).

---

Neater still might be:

```
def create_treeview(*types):
    store = gtk.ListStore(*types)
    ...
```

Now you can pass separate arguments to `create_treeview`:

```
myTree, myStore = b.create_treeview(int, str, str, int)
```

Or

```
myTree, myStore = b.create_treeview(*types)
```